# SAP HANA data provider for Microsoft ado.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, hana

I need to connect my C# web application with SAP HANA database using Entity Framework 6. I've got this documentation: [obsolete link](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/f3/5ec71c485e493aa20d0bd0e3bff06a/frameset.htm) (possibly, [Microsoft Entity Framework Support (SAP HANA Data Provider for Microsoft ADO.NET)](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/ac86b96b98984a7e9b5a3e8194db39ea.html) may correspond.)

This document explains how to use SAP HANA data provider for Microsoft ado.net. But I unable to find from where could I download SAP HANA data provider for Microsoft ado.net.

**Could any one provide me a link for the same?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is part of the SAP HANA client package.

Go to https://service.sap.com/hana, login, then click "Software download", and select your edition. Proceed with "SAP HANA Client 1.00", not with the proposed "Studio".

Answer (score 4):

You can get the ado.net driver (+ python, java, etc..) from this address: https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#hanatools